# Is there a way to use a custom base class on a DataContract entitiy in WCF?

Tags: wcf, datacontract

Is there a way to use a base class under a data contract entity on the client side?  In the generated code it explicitly inherits from object.  I have a base class that I use in my application architecture in order to perform cross-cutting tasks.  I'm wanting to integrate my existing business objects into the WCF service by making them partial classes.  It is working wonderfully, except that I can't seem to use the base class that I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several other options for adding functionality to a class on the client side.  Which one to use depends on the use case you're looking for.

If you all you want is to add new methods to the client version of the class, then you can use partial classes to add new methods to the generated class directly.

If you want to have several objects on the client side share a set of methods so they can be accessed polymophically, then you can use partial classes to add an interface to the class defining the new methods, create a helper class that provides the method definitions, and then delegate to the helper class in each DataContract object that implements the ineterface.

```
public interface IDoStuff 
{
  void DoStuff()
}

public interface IDoStuffContext
{
  int Data {get;}
  string Value {set;}
}

public class DoStuffHelper
{
  private IDoStuffContext _wrapped;
  public DoStuffHelper(IDoStuffContext wrapped) 
  {
    _wrapped = wrapped;
  }

  public void DoStuff() {
      if(_wrapped.Data == 10) {
         _wrapped.Value = "Hello World";
      }
  }
}

public partial class MyDataContract1 : IDoStuff
{
  private DoStuffHelper _helper = new DoStuffHelper(this);

  public void DoStuff() {
    _helper.DoStuff();
  }
}

public partial class MyDataContract2 : IDoStuff
{
  private DoStuffHelper _helper = new DoStuffHelper(this);

  public void DoStuff() {
    _helper.DoStuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, these were ideas I had.  Primarily the helper pattern.  I'll probably end up doing something like this.  Not all cross cutting concerns can be modeled this way without significant code redundancies, For instance `INotifyPropertyChanged`. My base class provided support for this; thankfully, the code generated entities provide support for this also, but other things may crop up that call specifically for a base class.  I'd really like to know why it explicitly set like this though.  I wish AOP actually became a thing. :(

Comment: What do you mean "actually became a thing".  There are plenty of frameworks that support AOP in .NET: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AOP_Frameworks_Rating.aspx.  Property change notification is a prime use case for AOP.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I'd like to see something integrated into the Microsoft development environment.  Its very fringe. Isn't it? If so, I wish it weren't. If not, its news to me. Maybe I should consider working with one of these tools on my next project.  Its kind of a fundamental decision, and its late in this project.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't believe this is possible using the standard proxy generator. The XSD code generator does not specify an actual base class nor do they allow one to be specified via parameter.

I believe the output you are seeing is due to the CodeDom classes that are used to do the actual code generation, which support various languages. It appears the C# generator, in the presence of no class inheritance, converts this to an explicit inheritance from `Object`. This is unfortunate because if it did not do this you could use partial classes to do what you're seeking.

I believe the simplest solution is to use Search and Replace, or write a macro to do this after you update service references.

Comment: That's annoying.  I wonder if there is a reason for this explicit declaration.  I'll just have to change the way I include cross-cutting functionality (maybe AOP -- kidding).   Also, its bad form to change generated code.  I never do it anyway.

Comment: I believe it is a trait of the CodeDom which does not provide a complete mapping for each of the languages it supports and tends to lose some things in translation. Agree completely re the modification of generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Does it makes sense in your application to create the base class on the Service, add a few [known types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) on its definition and extending it with partial implementation on the client side ?